# Unity Viewport size to Full HD?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

at the moment I start with Unity in 2D development for android. Before I develop in Unity i develop with LibGDX where I can the Viewport to a static screen resolution at 1080 * 1920, if the game starts on a smaller device for example 480 * 800 the game still looks pretty good. In Unity when I use a Orthographics Camera and set the width to 1080 and the height to 1920 it looks like a equal long quadrate and not portrait.
How can I use a static Camera which the Viewport is 1080 * 1920 and for other devices unity self charge the resolution for the game?

Sorry for my bad english :(

greetings coco07!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You're thinking about 2D engines. Unity is a 3D engine with a 2D extension (sort of). You set your camera up (doesn't matter what orthographic size you use), and it gets scaled to the viewport of the device it's running on. the size you set is the size of the viewport, in world units, along the y axis of the device's display. The width is set automatically based on the device's aspect ratio. You can see this by resizing the game window in unity. Doing that causes the visualization of the camera's bounds to change. To create a static camera, you'd have to manually add black borders around the edges (or at least I think you do), OR, better yet, create your game in a manner that runs on all aspects. You should consider aspect ratios between 4:3 and 16:9 for landscape and 3:4 to 9:16 for portrait games. This is specially important since many recent devices use on-screen system buttons (such as the google nexus and Xperia Z series) which means you get an aspect ratio of a little bit less that 16:9 (or a bit more, on tablets). This doesn't sound like much, but if you down-scale a 16:9 image to fit on those devices' screens, it looks ugly as hell.

Comment: Hey Arshia001, thanks for your awesome answer. Than I return to the LibGDX 2D Engine because Unity is to much learn stuff again :)

Comment: That's one option, but I'd seriously recommend against it, unless you're short on time. Unity is the ultimate tool for mobile development as proven by the number of mobile titles which are based on it. It's even been taking a pretty bold step up as a full PC game engine with its new updates, so it's definitely worth the time. It's all your choice, though...